# Workaround for "duplicate association path" NHibernate bug

Tags: .net, nhibernate

Consider a `Person` table where each name (first, last, middle, ...) are stored in a separate table `PersonName` and I want to select two different names for each Person.

The SQL would look something like:

```
SELECT firstName.VALUE, lastName.VALUE
FROM person p
inner join personName firstName on p.ID=firstName.PersonId AND firstName.Type='FIRSTNAME'
inner join personName lastName on p.ID=lastName.PersonId AND lastName.Type='LASTNAME'
```

I'd like to create this query with NHibernate. My first attempt was using `QueryOver` but I ran against an [NHibernate issue](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3472).

After that, I tried with `SelectSubQuery` but it was really slow + it makes filtering/sorting more difficult.

Is this at all possible or do I need to revert to perhaps building the SQL myself?

**Update**:
This has to be dynamic, I don't know upfront which PersonName.Type I'll have to select.

PS: I'm using Person+Names here as a simplified example.

Comment: You could use a schema-bound view and query from that to get around the limitation--I've had success with that before

Comment: No idea what a schema-bound view is, but we're using Oracle, so it is not available to us :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it looks like this will not be fixed in NHibernate (marked as 'Trivial' in their bug tracking system), I actually switched from Query-Over to HQL.

Doing exactly the same thing with HQL does not trigger the bug and works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a [table per class hierarchy](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/#inheritance-tableperclass). This means you would create a PersonName class and then subclass that for the First and Last name types (i.e. PersonFirstName, PersonLastName classes). Then you do the mapping and define the discrimator values for the Type property.

```
<class name="PersonName" table="PersonName">
    <id name="Id" type="Int64">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <discriminator column="Type" type="String"/>
    <property name="Value" />
    ...
    <subclass name="PersonFirstName" discriminator-value="FIRSTNAME">
        ...
    </subclass>
    <subclass name="PersonLastName " discriminator-value="LASTNAME">
        ...
    </subclass>
</class>
```

Then your Person class would have a reference to PersonFirstName and PersonLastName.

I hope there are good reasons for this table design because it seems overly complicated for such a basic thing as a name.

**update**

To further restrict down to language you could change them to collections and then use an extra condition on your join.

```
PersonFirstName fn = null;

var q = QueryOver<Person>()
.JoinAlias(
    x => x.FirstNames, 
    () => fn, 
    JoinType.InnerJoin, 
    Restrictions.Where<PersonFirstName>(x => x.Language = "en"));
```

Comment: Is it possible to use two columns as discriminator? ex: "Type" and "Language", if the name of a Person could be different in Chinese and English? (I'm starting the stretch the Person+Names abstraction here:)

Comment: I think the discriminator can only be one column.

Comment: While it is an interesting concept, I don't think I want to use this approach: the collections `.FirstNames` etc need to be dynamic.